# Creating Feature with content types imported by Feature

Tags: 7, features

Exporting several content types (7) from old website and importing them to new one worked perfectly.

After that i have done some basic changes in imported content types (changed widgets in few text fields (all widgets are default type)).

Now i want to make fresh backup of content types.
"Create feature" / Edit components - Content types: node
Now i can only choose "Article" and "Basic page". Content types i imported are not visible as an option.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open exisitng feature that contains content types and choose "Recreate", then click "Download". You will get new version of feature that will include all your changes.

Answer (score 1):

If your nodetype is already in a feature, they will not show up in the feature list.
You can disable the feature containing the nodetypes, now the nodetypes should appear.